# .NET version control system

Tags: c#, .net, exception, argumentexception

I have the following assemblies in my solution:

- Main Assembly (not strong-named);
- Class Library 1 (strong-named with v.1.0.0.0);
- Class Library 1 (strong-named with v.2.0.0.0);
- Class Library 2 (not strong-named).

These assemblies are connected to each other as illustrated below: [image: Assemblies dependency scheme]

> 'Main Assembly' dependens on 'Class Library 1' (v.2.0.0.0) and 'Class Library 2', 'Class Library 2' depends on 'Class Library 2' (v.1.0.0.0).

Class Library 1 code (both for v.1.0.0.0 and v.2.0.0.0):

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class
    {
    }
}
```

Class Library 2 code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class(ClassLibrary1.Class c)
    {
    }
}
```

Main Assembly code:

```
namespace MainAssembly
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassLibrary1.Class c1 = new ClassLibrary1.Class();
            ClassLibrary2.Class c2 = new ClassLibrary2.Class(c1);
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs without errors despite the fact that the versions of 'Class Library 1' assemblies do not match! Why?

At the same time, if I try to call the ClassLibrary2.Class constructor using Reflection (code is shown below), I get the runtime System.ArgumentException:

> Object of type 'ClassLibrary1.Class' cannot be converted to type 'ClassLibrary1.Class'.

```
namespace MainAssembly
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassLibrary1.Class c1 = new ClassLibrary1.Class();
            typeof(ClassLibrary2.Class).GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(new[]{ c1 });
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The compiler does not guess exactly what version of type it needs to use. If you look at the IL code below, you see that c1 object has type declared in an assembly 'Class Library 1' (v.2.0.0.0), and then it passed to the constructor ClassLibrary2.Class that takes the types from 'Class Library 1' (v.2.0.0.0).

```
.assembly extern ClassLibrary1
{
    .publickeytoken = (F3 A6 02 4F 9E A4 F3 DB )                         // ...O....
    .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern ClassLibrary2
{
    .ver 1:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern ClassLibrary1 as ClassLibrary_3
{
    .publickeytoken = (F3 A6 02 4F 9E A4 F3 DB )                         // ...O....
    .ver 1:0:0:0
}

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit MainAssembly.Program
   extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
    {
        .entrypoint
        // Code size       22 (0x16)
        .maxstack  1
         .locals init (
             [0] class [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary1.Class c1,
             [1] class [ClassLibrary2]ClassLibrary2.Class c2,
             [2] class MainAssembly.Class c3)
        IL_0000:  nop
        IL_0001:  newobj     instance void [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary.Class::.ctor()
        IL_0006:  stloc.0
        IL_0007:  ldloc.0
        IL_0008:  newobj     instance void [ClassLibrary2]ClassLibrary2.Class::.ctor(class [ClassLibrary_3]ClassLibrary.Class)
        IL_000d:  stloc.1
        IL_000e:  ldloc.0
        IL_000f:  newobj     instance void MainAssembly.Class::.ctor(class [ClassLibrary1]ClassLibrary.Class
        IL_0014:  stloc.2
        IL_0015:  ret
    } // end of method Program::Main
} // end of class Client.Program
```

Comment: Sounds like a design issue to me that you use two versions of the same library in one project.

Comment: @UweKeim, I do not use code like this in production, this question interests me because I want to develop my own compiler.

Comment: Looks like the compiler analyses the types/assembly versions as it goes. If the type can be inferred by another reference (in this case a constructor) then it will use that reference to decide the assembly. What happens if you add a new class `MainAssembly.Class(ClassLibrary1.Class c1)`, then append `MainAssembly.Class c3 = new MainAsssembly.Class(c1)` to your sample? I'd imagine there will be a compiler error?

Comment: @Xenolightning, there are no compile errors in your case, because types will be identical. I added IL code fragment in question.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant, I try to compile my project without Visual Studio (only with csc.exe), but get the same result. I don't have any .config files.

Comment: No idea how to do that, pretty sure that ClassLibrary1.dll v2 is going to overwrite ClassLibrary1.dll v1.

Comment: @HansPassant, but with Reflection this code fails.

Comment: Sure, you don't have the friendly C# compiler anymore to keep you out of trouble.  Objects of a type from the v1 assembly are fundamentally incompatible with an object of a type from the v2 assembly.  Type identity in .NET includes the [AssemblyVersion] of the assembly they came from.